# RequestLocationUpdate with Pending Intent and how to get the Location Provider(GPS, Network) status?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, location-provider

I have used Android SDK Location Manager to get the user location.

I am requesting the location information by using Pending Intent. I have used pending intent because my need to send the location information even the app is not running.

```
Intent mLocationIntent = new Intent(mContext,
            LocationIntentService.class);
mLocationUpdatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 1,
            mLocationIntent, 0);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mLocationUpdatePendingIntent);
```

Once registered with the above code I am getting the location information at onHandleIntent of LocationIntentService class.

But I don't have the onProviderEnabled or onProviderDisabled method to listen for the gps and network provider status. And also I dont want to use the fused location api.

How can I achieve both of these by requesting the location update using Pending Intent. Or else any other way to register for location information and also for the location provider status.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use your locationlistener instead an intent?

something like this:

```
LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  

                }
};
```

Then to do an update use:

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))    
                    manager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, mLocationListener, null);
```